# How to prevent Spring from generating default simpSessionId?

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am trying to set up spring with websockets and STOMP.

On the client, I send a header variable 
'simpSessionId':%session_id%

However, on receiving the message, spring it always places the supplied header in a key called nativeHeaders and a default simpSessionId in the header root.

```
{simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={SPRING.SESSION.ID=[5b1f11d0-ad92-4855-ae44-b2052ecd76d8], Content-Type=[application/json], X-Requested-With=[XMLHttpRequest], simpSessionId=[5b1f11d0-ad92-4855-ae44-b2052ecd76d8], accept-version=[1.2,1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[0,0], destination=[/mobile-server/ping], content-length=[15]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpSessionId=1, simpDestination=/mobile-server/ping}
```

Any ideas how to have spring pick up the supplied session id instead?

**Edited**

Ok, I have a mobile phone app and a website hitting the same server. I need to be able to set up a webocket on the mobile phone app.

On the mobile phone app, I login to the server through a traditional REST endpoint, and I receive a session-id in the response if successful.

I use webstomp-client on the mobile phone, Spring 4.1.9, Spring Security 4.1, Spring Session 1.2.0.

I would ideally login to the STOMP websocket on the socket CONNECT using a token, but I understand that his is currently impossible because webstomp-client doesn't pass custom headers on CONNECT.

I have two problems:

- How do I pass the session id that I retrieve on the REST Login in subsequent requests? I've tried adding headers such as SPRING.SESSION.ID, but stepping through the code I always see the message processing going back to the simpSessionId which is always defaulted to 1, 2 etc. I've tried extending the AbstractSessionWebsocketMessageBrokerConfigurer, but it doesn't pick up my session id, it always looks in the simpSessionAttributes, which is always empty.
- The code also seems to try to get the http session, which is a web browser scenario. I'm assuming I should just ignore this
- Sessions expire. What should be the strategy for a session that may have expired? Shouldn't I pass a remember-me style authentication token as well? Or should I rely on some everlasting stateless session? This is not clear to me and this aspect seems to be undocumented.

Obviously, I'm doing something very wrong. Here's my config:

@Configuration
  @EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds=1200)
  public class SessionConfig {

```
@Inject
ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager;

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(
        @Value("${spring.redis.host}") String host,
        @Value("${spring.redis.password}") String password,
        @Value("${spring.redis.port}") Integer port) {
    JedisConnectionFactory redis = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    redis.setUsePool(true);
    redis.setHostName(host);
    redis.setPort(port);
    redis.setPassword(password);
    redis.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redis;
}

@Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String,ExpiringSession> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      RedisTemplate<String, ExpiringSession> template = new RedisTemplate<String, ExpiringSession>();
      template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
      template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
      template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
      return template;
  }

@Bean
public <S extends ExpiringSession>SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends ExpiringSession> sessionRepositoryFilter(SessionRepository<S> sessionRepository) {
    return new SessionRepositoryFilter<S>(sessionRepository);
}

@Bean
  public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
          return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
  }

@Bean
public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy(){
    return new SmartSessionStrategy();
}

@Bean
  public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
          DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
          serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID"); 
          serializer.setCookiePath("/");
          serializer.setUseSecureCookie(true);
          serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$"); 
          return serializer;
  }
```

}

===

```
public class SessionWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    public SessionWebApplicationInitializer() {
    }

    public SessionWebApplicationInitializer(Class<?>... configurationClasses) {
        super(configurationClasses);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeSessionRepositoryFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
        Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("openSessionInViewFilter", new OpenSessionInViewFilter());
        if (registration == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Duplicate Filter registration for openSessionInViewFilter. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.");
        }
        registration.setAsyncSupported(false);
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = getSessionDispatcherTypes();
        registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, false,"/*");
    }

}
```

==

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig<S extends ExpiringSession> extends AbstractSessionWebsocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<S>{

    @Inject
    SessionRepository<S> sessionRepository;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");

        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/mobile-server");

        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/mobile-user");

    }

    @Override
    public void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setHandshakeHandler(new SessionHandShakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy()))
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS()
            .setSessionCookieNeeded(false)
            ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setMessageSizeLimit(512 * 1024);
        registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024);
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(40000);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketConnectHandler<S> webSocketConnectHandler(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate, UsorManager userMgr) {
        return new WebSocketConnectHandler<S>(messagingTemplate, userMgr);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketDisconnectHandler<S> webSocketDisconnectHandler(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate, WebSocketManager repository) {
        return new WebSocketDisconnectHandler<S>(messagingTemplate, repository);
    }

}
```

====

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurity extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    ApplicationContext context = null;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
            .nullDestMatcher().permitAll()
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/queue/errors").permitAll()
            .simpDestMatchers("/mobile-server/ping").authenticated()
            .simpDestMatchers("/mobile-server/csrf").authenticated()
            .simpDestMatchers("/mobile-server/**").hasRole("ENDUSER")
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/**", "/topic/**").hasRole("ENDUSER")
            .anyMessage().denyAll();
    }

}
```

===
I have removed some additional security configurations I have here for brevity sake.

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(100)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
private static final String REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE = "SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE";

@Inject
FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource;

@Inject
SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends ExpiringSession> sessionRepositoryFilter;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setSaltSource(saltSource);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userMgr);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    provider.setMessageSource(messages);
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider);

}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authenticationTokenProcessingFilter() throws Exception{
    return new AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
}

@Bean
public FilterSecurityInterceptor myFilterSecurityInterceptor(
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, 
        AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager,
        FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource){
    FilterSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new FilterSecurityInterceptor();
    interceptor.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    interceptor.setAccessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager);
    interceptor.setSecurityMetadataSource(securityMetadataSource);
    interceptor.setSecurityMetadataSource(metadataSource);
    return interceptor;
}

@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager(SiteConfig siteConfig){
    URLBasedSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new URLBasedSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setSiteConfig(siteConfig);

    WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
    webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler);

    return new AffirmativeBased(Lists.newArrayList(
            webExpressionVoter,
            new RoleVoter(),
            new AuthenticatedVoter()
    ));
}

public PasswordFixingAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, SaltSource saltSource){
    PasswordFixingAuthenticationProvider provider = new PasswordFixingAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userMgr);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    provider.setSaltSource(saltSource);

    return provider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(sessionRepositoryFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .antMatcher("/ws/**")
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/mobile/403")
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/ws").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/ws/websocket").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/ws/**").denyAll();           
       .anyRequest().requiresSecure()

    ;
}
```

}

===

```
  public class SmartSessionStrategy implements HttpSessionStrategy {

    private HttpSessionStrategy browser;

    private HttpSessionStrategy api;

    private RequestMatcher browserMatcher = null;

    public SmartSessionStrategy(){
        this.browser = new CookieHttpSessionStrategy();
        HeaderHttpSessionStrategy headerSessionStrategy = new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
        headerSessionStrategy.setHeaderName(CustomSessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor.SPRING_SESSION_ID_ATTR_NAME);
        this.api = headerSessionStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestedSessionId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return getStrategy(request).getRequestedSessionId(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewSession(Session session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        getStrategy(request).onNewSession(session, request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidateSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        getStrategy(request).onInvalidateSession(request, response);
    }

    private HttpSessionStrategy getStrategy(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(this.browserMatcher != null)
            return this.browserMatcher.matches(request) ? this.browser : this.api;

        return SecurityRequestUtils.isApiRequest(request) ? this.api : this.browser;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is based on invalid expectations to begin with. You cannot pass the session id and it's not meant to be passed in. You cannot login at the STOMP protocol level, it's not how it it's designed to work.

Although the STOMP protocol does allow for user credentials to be passed in the CONNECT frame that's more useful with STOMP over TCP. In an HTTP scenario we already have authentication and authorization mechanisms in place to rely on. By the time you get to the STOMP CONNECT, you would have had to pass authentication and authorization for the WebSocket handshake URL.

I would start with the Spring reference documentation on [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-authentication) for STOMP/WebSocket messaging if you haven't read that already:

> When a WebSocket handshake is made and a new WebSocket session is
>   created, Spring’s WebSocket support automatically propagates the
>   java.security.Principal from the HTTP request to the WebSocket
>   session. After that every message flowing through the application on
>   that WebSocket session is enriched with the user information. It’s
>   present in the message as a header.

In other words authentication is the same as for existing web applications. The URL at which the WebSocket endpoint is exposed is just another HTTP endpoint of the application. The same way all other HTTP endpoints are secured is the way the WebSocket handshake is secured. Just like for other HTTP endpoints you don't pass the session id. Instead you're within an existing HTTP session maintained through a cookie.

The handshake cannot be established unless Spring Security authenticates and authorizes the HTTP URL first. From there the STOMP session will pick up the authenticated user and Spring Security offers further ways to authorize individual STOMP messages.

That should all work seamlessly. There is no need to login via STOMP or to pass the Spring Session id at any time.

Comment: Added the config in the main question

Comment: "The code also seems to try to get the http session, which is a web browser scenario. I'm assuming I should just ignore this"

No you shouldn't ignore it. That's what the code expects. The authentication information is picked up from the HTTP handshake.

Comment: Ok, is there anything specific that seems to be wrong in the config? 

So, there is two levels: authentication and session. 

I've been focusing so far on passing the session token through a header. How can I pass it through a header and process it on the server in order that this is properly transferred in the HTTP handshake and get a session instantiated based on the passed session id?

Comment: In addition the setSessionCookieNeeded(false) part of the config is almost certainly wrong as indicated in the Javadoc for the method, most Java applications rely on that to maintain an HTTP session for the user on the server side.

Comment: What if you are passing the sessionId in the request header instead of a cookie? Then it would not be wrong.